# how to pass calculated values using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

the following values are to calculate the user entered values, these are calculated and passed to the text field,

```
if(computer && monitor && tv && laptop && cell)
      { // getting the text field the values and calculated 
         var valueCom = document.getElementById("computer").value ;
         var valueMon = document.getElementById("monitor").value ; 
         var valueTv  = document.getElementById("tv").value ; 
         var valueLap = document.getElementById("laptop").value ;
         var valueCel = document.getElementById("cell").value;

         var finalCom = valueCom * 0.1818937134 ;        
         var finalMon = valueMon * 0.056842 ;    
         var finalTv  = valueTv  * 0.056842 ;           
         var finalLap = valueLap * 0.090947 ;        
         var finalCel = valueCel * 0.045473 ;     

         var totalTonnes = finalCom + finalMon + finalTv + finalLap + finalCel; 

         var totalCarbon  = totalTonnes * 1 ; 
         var totalTree    = totalTonnes * 17.1969 ;
         var totalPetrol  = totalTonnes * 286.396 ;
         var totalPlastic = totalTonnes * 646.421 ; 
// pass this above four values to the textfield

      }
<input type="text" name="carbon" >
<input type="text" name="tree" >
<input type="text" name="petrol" >
<input type="text" name="plastic" >
// field to pass values here
```

how to pass this values using java script to the text field. can anyone help me please

Comment: where you want to set ?

Answer (score 1):

you want to add id to text field,

```
<input type="text" name="carbon" id="carbon">
<input type="text" name="tree" id="tree">
<input type="text" name="petrol" id="petrol">
<input type="text" name="plastic" id="plastic">
```

then after javascript,

```
document.getElementById("carbon").value=totalCarbon; 
document.getElementById("tree").value=totalTree;    
document.getElementById("petrol").value=totalPetrol;  
document.getElementById("plastic").value=totalPlastic;
```

and also you can use to value set by name,

```
document.getElementsByName("plastic")[0].value = totalPlastic;
......
```

or,

```
 document.getElementById("plastic").setAttribute('value',totalCarbon);
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign your resultant text field with id="result" or anything. Then, you can put your result as `$(#result).val(yourCalcultedResult);`

Comment: Except the OP hasn't tagged the question with a library nor indicated its use in the question. You haven't said which library you're using, and there's a syntax error.

Comment: this code using only javascript and html. not include jquery.

Answer (score 0):

set the value property

```
document.getElementById("carbon").value = totalCarbon;
document.getElementById("tree").value = totalTree;
document.getElementById("petrol").value = totalPetrol;
document.getElementById("plastic").value = totalPlastic;
```

and set the ids to the respective elements

```
<input type="text" name="carbon" id="carbon" >
<input type="text" name="tree" id="tree" >
<input type="text" name="petrol" id="petrol" >
<input type="text" name="plastic" id="plastic" >
```

Or **if you still want to use names only**, then make it

```
document.getElementsByName("carbon")[0].value = totalCarbon;
document.getElementsByName("tree")[0].value = totalTree;
document.getElementsByName("petrol")[0].value = totalPetrol;
document.getElementsByName("plastic")[0].value = totalPlastic;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByName("carbon")[0].value = totalCarbon;
document.getElementsByName("tree")[0].value = totalTree;
document.getElementsByName("petrol")[0].value = totalPetrol;
document.getElementsByName("plastic")[0].value = totalPlastic;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your controls are in a form, like:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="carbon">
  <input type="text" name="tree">
  <input type="text" name="petrol">
  <input type="text" name="plastic">
  ...
</form>
```

then you can get a reference to the form and access them as named properties of the form, e.g.

```
var form = document.forms[0];
form.carbon.value = totalCarbon;
form.tree.value = totalTree;
...
```

Just make sure you don't give form controls a name that is the same as a form property, like *submit* or *name*, as these will shadow the form's default properties of the same name (so you can't call *form.submit()* or access the form's name, if it has one).

Answer (score 0):

```
//globally i declared carbon, tree, petrol, plastic
  document.getElementById("carbon").value   = carbon ; 
  document.getElementById("tree").value     = tree ; 
  document.getElementById("petrol").value   = petrol ; 
  document.getElementById("plastic").value  = plastic ;
```